# How to handle downvoting sprees

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

Are there any systems in place to combat down-voting sprees? Presumably I offended someone (I really don't know how or whom) so they went to my page and downvoted every question I ever asked back-to-back-to-back all within seconds of each other.

[image]

I don't really care because site rep doesn't matter *that much* to me, but I was curious if there are any algorithms in place to detect/prevent this type of behavior.

Comment: Take a look at previous posts under the [serial-voting] tag